# Convert Text to PNG - (NexusFont alternative)

Tags: windows-7, png

I need an alternative for NexusFont, or some soft that convert Text to PNG.

Custom folder with a list of fonts for PNG image - background transparent - dimensions at least 5000x5000px.

Unfortunately, NexusFont does not allow me to use background transparent and watermark the font that was used.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chP4m.png

The application should run on Windows 7 and cost no more than $100.

Comment: What precisely are you trying to do - what is the context in which this request is being made? If we understand why you believe you need this, we will be better able to advise you.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, generally for logos!

Comment: You could just type the text in a graphics program like Paint, gimp, etc., and then just save as a PNG with transparency.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, the most important thing is that I can't use a custom folder with my list of fonts!

Comment: So what you're really asking for is a way to generate font specimen sheets in PNG format with transparent backgrounds?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Yes! and dimensions at least 5000x5000px.

Comment: You should edit your question to ask for that, rather than the much less clear "need to convert text to PNG"

Comment: Thanks for the details, @lucasrutherford! I've integrated price & OS directly with your question and will now delete the correspinding comments (to keep things clear and easy to follow). Please consider to **[edit]** your question once more and add the other details (including whether you meant AUD, USD, CAD :)) Thanks!